# Authentication failure!

Tags: authentication

At the time of installation i gave login password and that was the login keyring password and authentication password.. then once in user accounts->login options in dat for password options i set as none and then i locked.. after that the passwd which i gave at the time of installation remained as login keyring passwd but wen i entered that passwd for authentication while installing some packages it's showing authentication failure.pls try again.. so i couldnt download any packages or updates..  is there any possibilities to change/reset the authentication password.. pls help me..

Comment: Did you try this:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-root-password

Answer (score 0):

Setting a blank password, without disabling password authentication for performing administrative tasks, tends to break an Ubuntu system. Blank passwords don't work for all important forms of authentication, and they will prevent you from performing administrative tasks.

**Fortunately, this an be completely fixed pretty easily.**

As [Tautvydas Miknevičius](https://askubuntu.com/users/70862/tautvydas-miknevicius) has suggested, you can simply [reset the password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-root-password) (to something that is not blank).